# fancyhdr works perfectly on first page, but messes up top of second page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

So I have used the package \fancyhdr{} to insert a logo in the top of my first page in a document, this works perfectly. 
The problem is just that on the second page, all my text is moved down the same amount as on the first page, this is super annoying.

The code looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[tableaux]{prooftrees}
\renewcommand*\linenumberstyle[1]{#1}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[euler]{textgreek}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-10em}   
\fancyhead[R]{
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{RucLogoAlt.jpg}
      }
 \author{Ask Harup Sejsbo & 64033}
\title{A requirements sepcification approach to playfull installations}
 \maketitle
 \thispagestyle{fancy}
 \section{Problem One}
 \end{document}
```

and this results in this very nice first page 
[image]

\begin{document}

But now the second page has this giant gap in the top

[image]

How can i change this, so my second page looks normal?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code fragments to complete small document, which we can test as it is. It seems, that you need to have two page styles: one for the first page (`\thispagestyle{...}`) and on for all other pages (`\pagestyle{...}`.

Comment: ahh, all right, so when i write \thispagestyle{...}, i also need \pagestyle{}? and what do i need to put in \pagestyle{} to make it work "normally"?

Comment: hmm, when i write \pagestyle, overleaf does not seem to reckonize it, do i need to include something?

Comment: Sorry, we cant confirm this. You still not complete your code sample to MWE (Minimal Working Example), which we can test and after then make suggestion how to solve your problem. Mentioned commands from my previous comments works for sure, but, as I already said, we don't know how you used them. Please again, provide MWE!

Comment: just edited with the two last lines to make the snippet complete